# How to use DOM object for Current PHP page

Tags: php, dom

In my php page I am getting a list of cities and events dynamically from a database. Then I'm passing this sql data to jquery to render a table with the data. Sample table created by jquery could be like:

```
<tr>
    <td id='cityMumbai'>Mumabai</td>
    <td id='program1Start>11/11/11</td>
    <td id='program2Start'>11/15/11</td>
<tr>
```

Now I've come to know that DOM can be used to manipulate table structure in php.

I saw various reference, and found it is being used to create a new page. Means the created paged is saved physically.

Possible Pseudo Code:

```
{
<span id="eventRows">
  <? $object = new DOMDocument;//it should pick this specific instance  ?>
  <? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rProgList,MYSQL_ASSOC)):?>
                        <? // write code to check if current cityname exitst?
   $td = $object->getElementById($row['cityname']);
    if(!$td.exists): ?>
   <tr><td id="<? echo $row['cityname'];?>"><? echo $row['cityname'];?></td></tr>
   <?  else : ?>
   <?
        //code to insert only event information in the current city object
         $td.append("dfkjsdflkjasdhflkjsfh");
    ?>

     <? endif; ?>
     <? endwhile; ?>
  </span>
}
```

Can I use DOM in PHP to modify the page output, only... replacing the task jquery is doing using PHP. Not to modify a physical copy of it.

Comment: Yes, just use the DOM to create the table from the data you've gotten from the DB.

Comment: I am not able to follow documentation on how to do it. Can you please help. Added possible pseudo code.